# Java Swing Class Objects

Tags: java, swing

Question is about the object cont in mainWindow, I cant use it!

I got a Package (View) containing mainWindow and main. In my main I got the code:

```
package View;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import Controller.mainController;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainWindow view = new mainWindow();
                mainController cont = new mainController(view);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

in my mainWindow, I got:

```
public class mainWindow {
public mainWindow() {
    initialize();
}
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 728, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton ButtonStartGame = new JButton("Start Game");
    ButtonStartGame.setToolTipText("Start the game");
    ButtonStartGame.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonStartGame.setBounds(12, 189, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(ButtonStartGame);
    ButtonStartGame.addActionListener(e->cont.StartGame());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What do you try to achieve with `ButtonStartGame.addActionListener(e->cont.StartGame())`?

Comment: BTW, please check your naming. Class names start with an uppercase character. Variables, members, etc. start with a lowercase

Comment: Question is, why cant I use the object cont in mainWindow, the object is created in main(String[] args). 
StartGame() is a function in mainController class, the function just prints out "hello".
The error I get is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 cont cannot be resolved"

Comment: First of all, `e->cont.StartGame()` is not a valid java syntax.

Comment: You defined `cont` within the try-catch block of the main method. It's visible only there.

Comment: the lambda function e->cont.StartGame() works if I create the mainController object in mainWindow, like mainController cont = new mainController(view);, the problem is that the program crash when I try to use the view object in mainController with this approach, this is why Im trying to create them in main. I've removed the try-catch, still cant reach cont in mainWindow.

Comment: Figured it out. Java Swing is all new to me, I never created a instance of the button inside mainWindow (public JButton ButtonStartGame), then I moved the lambda function to my mainController constructor. Now clicking the "Start Game" button will go to the function StartGame().